# batch members communication settings

Tags: profile

Is it possible to change a communications preference for several members using profiles? I can't find how to do it. If I select "Contact" while having members filtered Civi won't find the profile. But if I select Member from profile I can't bulk-change communication preferences.

Am I doing stuff wrong?

Answer (score 3):

1/ Create a Profile that includes the required Comm Pref fields (this would be a Profile that ONLY contacts Contact type fields, not membership fields)

2/ Adv Search

3/ set your 'membership criteria' as required to find the relevant contacts

4/ use the 'batch update' or 'update multiple contacts' Action (4.6 and 4.7 have different descriptors

5/ you should then be able to bulk update

i just did this on dmaster.demo.... and it worked fine but maybe i am misreading your problem

Comment: Great. then pls help StackExchange work usefully for others by +1 the answer and 'accepting' it - that way others now this was a valid answer and helps everyone